# How to pass value dynamically based on media query

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular7

In my product section there are around 300 products so for pagination I have used ngx-pagination plugin. So products should  be displayed based on media query. for an eg I have to pass the value (In Media query) for 1600px to 1200px should have `itemsPerPage:30`, 1199 to 768 `itemsPerPage:24`

How to achieve this?

```
<ecom-section-box>
    <ecom-card-wc-5 *ngFor="let data of dataArray4  | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 30, currentPage: p } " [data]="data"></ecom-card-wc-5>
</ecom-section-box>
<div class="card card2">
    <span class="pagination-alignment">
        <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event" ></pagination-controls>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get window width on `init`

```js
public innerWidth: any;
ngOnInit() {
  this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
}
```

If you wanna keep it updated on resize:

```js
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
  this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
}
```

You can use this code to check if the window size is `1600px to 1200px` or `1199 to 768` and set the `itemsPerPage` accordingly.

**How you can use this code:**

```js
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
  this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
  if (this.innerWidth <= 1600 && this.innerWidth >= 1200) {
    itemsPerPage = 30;
  } else if (this.innerWidth <= 1199 && this.innerWidth >= 768) {
    itemsPerPage = 24;
  }
}
```

Comment: you have the variable with the value you can use that variable in the html as you are using other variables

Comment: so you can use like this `paginate: { itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage(this will be the variable which we are setting when screen have specific width), currentPage: p }`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `BreakpointObserver` from [`@angular/cdk/layout`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview).

```
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { of, EMPTY } from 'rxjs'

queryValues: Record<string, number> = {
  '(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px)': 24,
  '(min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1600px)': 30,
};

itemsPerPage: number;

constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) { }

ngOnInit() {
  const queries = Object.keys(this.queryValues)
  this.breakpointObserver.observe(queries).pipe(
    switchMap(state => {
      const activeQuery = queries.find(q => state.breakpoints[q]);
      return activeQuery ? of(this.queryValues[activeQuery]) : EMPTY
    })
  ).subscribe(queryValue => this.itemsPerPage = queryValue)
}
```